# A problem is NP-hard iff its complement is coNP-complete

Tags: complexity-theory, complexity-classes

$A$ is NP-hard iff $\overline{A}$ is $coNP$-hard, where $\overline{A}$ does mean complement of $A$.

I can't figure out why it is true. Let $A\in NP-hard$. I know that each problem in $NP$ is polynomially reducible to $A$.  So, let's "negate" $A$, then by definition: $\overline{A}\in coNP$.  However, I am not sure why $\overline{A}\in coNP-hard$.  Could you explain it me ?

My intution is that $NP$ and $coNP$ contains only decision problems, using this fact we can use machine for $A$ and negate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Definition**: co$NP = \{A \mid \overline{A} \in NP \}$
**Claim**: $A$  is $NP$-hard iff $\overline{A}$ is co$NP$-hard.
**Proof**:
Assume $A  \text{ is } NP\text{-hard}$ ($\Rightarrow$). Then by definition
$$ \forall L \in NP, \ \ x \in L \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in A \ \ (\text{ polynomial reducible})$$
equivalently
$$ \forall L \in NP, \ \ x \notin L \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \notin A \ \ (\text{ polynomial reducible})$$
implies
$$ \forall L \in NP, \ \ x \in \overline{L} \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in \overline{A} \ \ (\text{ polynomial reducible})$$
meaning $\overline{L} \in$ co$NP$ and reducible to $\overline{A}$, and thus $\overline{A} \text{ is co}NP\text{-hard}$.

Assume  $\overline{A} \text{ is co}NP\text{-hard}$ ($\Leftarrow$). Then moving in the backward direction as above:

$$ \forall L \in NP, \ \ x \in \overline{L} \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in \overline{A} \ \ (\text{ polynomial reducible})$$
equivalently
$$ \forall L \in NP, \ \ x \notin L \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \notin A \ \ (\text{ polynomial reducible})$$
and so 
$$ \forall L \in NP, \ \ x \in L \Longleftrightarrow f(x) \in A \ \ (\text{ polynomial reducible})$$
meaning $A$ is $NP$-hard.

---

**Update:**

If $L \in NP$ then there exists a NDTM $M_1$ running in polynomial time such that:

- if $x\in L$ then $M_1(x)=\text{"yes"}$ for **some** computation paths of $M$.
- if $x\notin L$ then $M_1(x)=\text{"no"}$ for **all** computation paths of $M_1$.

If $L \in coNP$ then there exists a NDTM $M_2$ running in polynomial time such that:

- if $x\in L$ then $M_2(x)=\text{"yes"}$ for **all** computation paths of $M_2$.
- if $x\notin L$ then $M_2(x)=\text{"no"}$ for **some** computation paths of $M_2$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64530/discussion-between-fade2black-and-haskell-fun).

Answer (score 1):

This argument is given for any complexity class.

If $C$ is a complexity class (for your question NP) and $L$ is $C-Hard$ (an 'identical' argument can be for complete languages):

If $A \in coC$ so $\bar A \in C$  so $ \bar A \le L$: ($\phi$ is the Karp-reduction for that matter)

$ \exists \phi.x\in \bar A \iff \phi(x)\in L $

Since it's iff the negation is:

$ \exists \phi.x\notin \bar A \iff \phi(x) \notin L$

Hence, (by definition of complementary)

$ \exists \phi.x\in A \iff \phi(x) \in \bar L$

$A \le \bar L \implies \bar L \in coC-Hard$

Negating the answer of an NP Turing machine won't help you to decide a language in coNP (except for trivial cases like language in P), since by definition an NP Turing machine accepts iff **there exist** an accepting branch in its' computation.

For simplicity, assume your NP Turing machine always has a rejecting branch in every computation (we can assume it for every NP Turing machine, why?), negating the answer will result in the trivial language $\Sigma $* every-time.